# How to post links and commands?

Tags: support, chat

How do I post links in comments and commands in chat?

Whenever I post a link with *a tag* in comments, it doesn't work. And whenever I post a command with `backtics` in chat, it also doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you asking multiple questions in the same post? You are asking how to do different times in different places, which doesn't seem to fit in the same post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chat uses a more limited version of markdown, most of the formatting you're used to should still work. For example:

Posting links: `[link text](http://linkuri)`

Posting tag links: `[tag:tagname]`

Posting images: `imageuri` (or `!imageuri` if the link doesn't end with an image extension)

Posting code: wrap in backticks like normal

A lot of content will also onebox, for example posting a question link or an answer link from any Stack Exchange site will onebox in chat, images will onebox and certain media will (for example, YouTube links)